# How to use Recurring Dates with Views properly?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I am trying to use ***recurring dates*** for one of my content types (*Event*) to limit the amount of *Event* records.

I would like to have one Event record created for all dates of that Event.
For example if an Event occurs every week for a year I have 1 record instead of 52.

Still I would like to see 52 separate lines in the related View because I would like to be able to sort/filter the View to see current week's Events only.

How to set up a Events View for that data so that each view line shows one date only ?

I would like a View to return a list like this...

```
 - Event A  12-10-2011 
 - Event B  12-11-2011
 - Event A  12-12-2011
 - Event B  12-13-2011 
 - Event A  12-14-2011 
 - Event B  12-15-2011
```

(Event A and B are recurring every second day )

...instead of a list like this:

```
 - Event A  
    - 12-10-2011
    - 12-12-2011
    - 12-14-2011
 - Event B 
    - 12-11-2011
    - 12-13-2011
    - 12-15-2011
 - Event A  
    - 12-10-2011
    - 12-12-2011
    - 12-14-2011
 - Event B 
    - 12-11-2011
    - 12-13-2011
    - 12-15-2011
 - Event A  
    - 12-10-2011
    - 12-12-2011
    - 12-14-2011
 - Event B 
    - 12-11-2011
    - 12-13-2011
    - 12-15-2011
```

Comment: Please note I know how to do it without recurring dates but I specifically need to limit the amount of data to be stored in and especially entered into the database. That is why I would prefer to use recurring dates or another simillar solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I found how to set this up an easy way:

1. Go to your **View**
2. Go to **Displays** --> `<your display name,  for example Page>` --> Edit
3. Select **Format** : **Table**
4. Add a date field:
5. Select a Content: `<your date field name>`
6. You will see Configure field: Content: `<your date field name>`
7. Go to **"Multiple field settings"**
8. Uncheck **"Display all values in the same row"**

> If checked, multiple values for this field will be shown in the same
>   row. If not checked, each value in this field will create a new row.
>   If using group by, please make sure to group by "Entity ID" for this
>   setting to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "unformatted list" and filter your dates with "greater than or equal" now to show current and upcoming events.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Display Suite](http://www.drupal.org/project/ds) for displaying the events (Show: Display Suite) you can do something like this in a custom module. Remember to change 'mymodule' and 'field_date' to correspond your module and date field names.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ds_views_row_render_entity_alter()
 */
function mymodule_ds_views_row_render_entity_alter(&$content, &$context) {
  //Display only the current date value from repeating dates
  $date_field_name = 'field_date';
  if (isset($content[$date_field_name]) && count($content[$date_field_name]['#items']) > 1) {
    // Modify the view, or the content render array in the context of a view.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content[$date_field_name]['#items']); ++$i) {
      if($content[$date_field_name]['#items'][$i]['value'] != $context['row']->field_data_field_date_field_date_value) {
        unset($content[$date_field_name][$i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you are just using fields as your Show option you can probably do something similar with View's hooks.