# Group repeating dates in Views

Tags: 7, views, datetime

**I have this scenario:**
The contenttype "event" has a date-field (with repeat-options). All repeating events are repeated for a certain timespan once a week.

**I want to achieve this views-block:**

- Show me all repeating events (got this to work with condition
  eventdate:rrule not empty).
- Group by Event-Id and don't show me every repeating event (because
  the description text of the event contains the human-readable
  repeat-logic ... e.g. every tuesday at 12.00)

**My Problem is:**
I activated "Use aggregation" in the view and wanted to group the events by node-id, but the date field (field_data_field_event_date_field_event_date_value) is automatically added to the "GROUP BY"-SQL part when i do this (and i can't remove it)

Am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: Have you seen this question: [How to use Recurring Dates with Views properly?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/17015/594)

Comment: Yes - I saw this, but the solution of this problem is my starting point :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problems and managed to fix it by enabling Aggregation on the view plus enabling 'Distinct'.

Comment: Please add "some more details" (instructions) to your answer. That should help to have it not show up in the "Low quality posts" review queue ... Just trying to get you going on this site, ok?