# Recurring events - retrieving/displaying the dates for the current "instance" of the event

Tags: datetime

I have an events page on my (D7) site, and the admin can set up recurring events.

When creating a list of the events, I see the recurring events come through in the right place intermingled with the non-recurring events.  However, their dates don't show up right:

My "normal" date fields only ever show the date of the first event.  There's an answer to this issue [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17015/how-to-use-recurring-dates-with-views-properly), but that requires table layout.  I'd prefer not to have to use table layout.  Any idea how I could do this without it?

Secondly, I'm using a pre-process field (called `big_date`) to create a second date field but with a different display to the first, so I can display the same date in different formats simultaneously.  How could my code here know which of the many dates in `$vars['node']->field_date_and_time[LANGUAGE_NONE]` is the one relating to the "current" instance of the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke briefly about this to a Drupal expert I know, and he suggested moving to using Views and the Fields view type as apparently the integration between the Date module and Views is very good.

At present, I'm using a View but also using Viewmodes and the preprocess field.  His point was that all of this could instead be accomplished by just using my existing content type, not using a custom viewmode but using the Fields view type.  And that this should be less buggy.

Comment: I'm not going to mark my own answer as "The Answer" just yet, in case someone else comes up with a more useful one!  But I might in future.

Comment: In the end we went with the _Panel fields_ View type as this provides both good field functionality and good layout functionality, both of which we need.